# Firebase iOS - guarantees on FDataSnapshot when calling observeSingleOfEventType

Tags: ios, firebase, setvalue

I would like clarification on what Firebase guarantees about the FDataSnapshot returned from observeSingleEventOfType.  In particular, [the iOS docs state:](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-guarantees)

> Value events are always triggered last and are guaranteed to contain
>   updates from any other events which occurred before that snapshot was
>   taken.

Does this also guarantee that updates occurring AFTER observeSingleEventOfType is called are NOT included?

For example in the following code:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"someUrl"];
[ref setValue:@{@"someKey1" : @"someValue1"}];
[ref observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue 
    withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        // is it ever possible that snapshot will contain someKey2?
}
[ref setValue:@{@"someKey2" : @"someValue2"}];
```

I'm wondering if it's ever possible for the snapshot to contain "someKey2," or does the snapshot only include updates that occurred before observeSingleEventOfType was called?

Comment: Careful with this as you are mixing synchronous writes with an asynchronous read. It would be technically possible for the code that writes someKey2 to occur before the read completes, and therefor any code within the block to occur after that set Value. While setValue is blisteringly fast, I've found it's always safer to write async and don't try to read the data until the write block successfully returns. That technique avoids the problem to start with.

Comment: What's the practical thing you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm writing some base classes in an attempt to make Firebase a little more native on iOS (similar to Parse).  One is FBObject (like Parse's PFObject), which I'd like to be the superclass of all my model objects, and which would handle synchronization to Firebase (choosing a good storage structure, adding indexes, supporting pointers, handling updates, etc).  Two methods I'd like on FBObject are "setObject:forKey:withBlock:" and "objectForKey:"  In general I'm trying to understand what guarantees I have from Firebase to see if those 2 methods are feasible (even while offline).

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the tip.  My only problem with Firebase's "setValue:withCompletionBlock:" (or related async update methods) is if the client is offline the completion block is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setValue()` is not an event; you're confused here. An event is something you can pass into `observe[Single]Event*()`, and they are [enumerated here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types).

Firebase is not synchronous and it won't wait for your write to complete. However, if you listen for `ChildAdded` and `observeSingleEventOfType()` of `value`, then all the child keys in the "snapshot" will have already triggered `ChildAdded` events.

If you want to wait for the write to complete, use `withCompletionBlock`:

```
[ref setValue:@"I'm writing data" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
    // start your listeners here
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Kato, indeed I was confusing terms.  "setValue:withCompletionBlock" is almost what I need (see comments above for my goal), except it never gets called if the client is offline.  I am looking for a way to know when a write completes even while offline.  Given there doesn't seem to be a Firebase method for this, I'm now attempting to use an in-memory cache to make updates available immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure what that would even mean. The write "completes" when it completes (i.e. gets saved to the database). If you listen to observeEvent() the ChildAdded event fires locally whether online or off, so you shouldn't ever concern yourself with online/offline/local/remote.

Comment: Thanks @Kato.  Sorry for the ambiguity, by "complete" I meant locally - i.e. the write task has been successfully queued and saved to disk locally so that even if the app is, for example, offline and forced to quit, the write task is guaranteed to eventually reach firebase servers.